# is filtergrid available in gxt version 2.2.3?

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am using gxt version 2.2.3. i wanted to use filtergrid available on examples demo http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:filtergrid. is it available in 2.2.3 version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the same applies for 2.2.x releases. Check out the [corresponding example of filter grid in version 2](http://www.sencha.com/examples-2/#filtergrid).

**References:**

- [The (legacy) showcase for Ext-GWT 2.x](http://www.sencha.com/examples-2/).
- [The official API docs on sencha.com](http://www.sencha.com/gxtdocs/).